# How to remove daily mean from minute data in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mean

I have a pandas dataframe with a minute datetime index:

| Index | Col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-25 09:01:00 | 5 |
| 2022-12-25 09:10:00 | 15 |
| 2022-12-25 11:12:00 | 10 |
| 2022-12-26 10:05:00 | 2 |
| 2022-12-26 12:29:00 | 2 |
| 2022-12-26 13:56:00 | 5 |

I want to remove the daily average from this data, resulting in this dataframe (here 10 for the first day and 3 for the second day):

| Index | Col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-12-25 09:01:00 | -5 |
| 2022-12-25 09:10:00 | 5 |
| 2022-12-25 11:12:00 | 0 |
| 2022-12-26 10:05:00 | -1 |
| 2022-12-26 12:29:00 | -1 |
| 2022-12-26 13:56:00 | 2 |

Comment: `df['Col1'] -= df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['Col1'].transform('mean')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming df is your dataframe, this should do the trick:

```
for day, df_group in df.groupby(by=df.index.day):
    
    df.loc[df_group.index,"Col1"] -= df_group["Col1"].mean()
```

Comment: Note: using `transforrm('mean')` avoids for loop and thus is more efficient (answer noted in  Quang Hoang comment).